# Doctrine unexpected behavior on bidirectional relations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I define two entities with bidirectional relations:

**One**

```
\App\Entity\Product:
...
  manyToOne:
    productSet:
      targetEntity: App\Entity\ProductSet
      inversedBy: products
      cascade: ["all"]
      joinColumn:
        onDelete: RESTRICT
...
```

**And two**

```
\App\Entity\ProductSet:
...
  oneToMany:
    products:
      targetEntity: App\Entity\Product
      mappedBy: productSet
      cascade: ['all']
...
```

If I drop all related `Product` entities, the related `productSet` entity automatically dropped too. And I don't understand why. How I prevent this behavior?

Doctrine version 2.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to docs - https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

and you have `cascade: ['all']` - the behavior is as expected

Comment: Set `cascade: ["persist"]` on the `Product` solved this problem. Thanks!